# safely comparing two strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

So I want to compare two strings, sometimes one of them will be of type "unicode" and sometimes one of them will be of type "str".

This is what I've currently got:

```
def poll_change(self):
    ''' Returns a tuple (has_changed, new_element_str) '''

    new_element = self.find_element()
    old_element = self.read_element_str()

    # TODO: handle compare correctly
    if type(new_element) is not type(old_element):
        changed = False
    else:
        changed = new_element != old_element

    return changed, new_element
```

what would be the best solution for this?
Right now I am just returning `False` if the types of the strings are unequal, but I would like to compare them anyways.

I would get an error if I would compare unicode with str for example.
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/difflib.py:433: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  a[besti-1] == b[bestj-1]`

I am using `Python 2.7`

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> u"a" == "a"
True
>>> "a" == "a"
True
>>> u"a" == u"a"
True
```

So what is the problem? Or do you mean you want to compare type too?

Comment: I get a warning in the console if I compare two strings with different types.

"Warning: ... Will assume unequal", something like that

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/difflib.py:433: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  a[besti-1] == b[bestj-1]:`

Comment: Weird... I haven't seen it before. Let's wait for someone who knows.